# Create an element based on a model while created an element of another model?

Tags: django

I'm pretty sure my question isn't clear but I didn't know how to put it.

The thing is : I have a `Task` model, and a `TaskHistory` model. When I create a Task model, I want automatically to create an associated `TaskHistory` object.
For example, I want to create a Task at `datetime.now()`, with the value "example", and when I do this, a `TaskHistory` object is created, with

```
created_on = datetime.now()
last_modification = datetime.now()
old_value = "example"
new_value = "example".
```

Can I do that in the model field of my `Task` model ?

I'm pretty new to Django.

Edit : the two models are linked to each other, my `TaskHistory` object would have `task = Task` if it's created like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the fields you've specified is available on the TaskHistory model you could override the `create()` method.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    #other fields snipped for brevity
    history = models.ForeignKey(TaskHistory)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        task = cls(**kwargs)
        history_kwargs = {'created_on':datetime.now(), 'last_modification':datetime.now(), 'old_value':'None', 'new_value': 'wee'}
        history = TaskHistory(**history_kwargs)
        history.save()
        task.history = history
        return task
```

and in your view or what have you call it like this

```
task = Task.create(insert_values_here_for_Task)
task.save()
```

Comment: Actually I was not clear, but this was the contraty : in the TaskHistory class I have task = models.ForeignKey(Task).
But anyway, understood the process, thanks, will look if it's ok for me !

Comment: You can simplify your model by removing one of the foreignkey relationships. Django gives you a link between the two objects.

Comment: All right so I removed task = models.ForeignKey(Task) in my TaskHistory class and put history = models.ForeignKey(TaskHistory) in my Task class, but I have the error 'undefined name "TaskHistory"'. What do ?

Comment: Import it? :) Or wrap it in `''`.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this:

1. Override the [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects) method on your Task model.
2. Use the [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) signal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I do that inside my Task class ?

taskhistory = TaskHistory(task = self, field = "", old_value = "Just created", new_value = "Just created")


\n    taskhistory.save()

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it by using [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import Task

@receiver(post_save, sender=Task)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    task=sender
    history_kwargs = {'created_on':datetime.now(), 'last_modification':datetime.now(), 'old_value':'None', 'new_value': 'wee'}
    history = TaskHistory(**history_kwargs)
    history.save()
    task.history = history
    task.save
```